# View postman request when redirects

Tags: postman

I am using Postman to submit request. Server responds with

```
HTTP/1.0 302 Found
Location: https://services.****.com/*/***/ed36317f-8d77-4d62-9926-f9700bee9b6c
Server: ****
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0
```

Postman follows this redirect. I wish to see this new request in Postman console. Can someone tell me how I can view how Postman formed new request?

Comment: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/4474  I see comment from Postman team "I do see the value in showing intermediate requests in the Console directly though, so I'm going to add this as a feature request :)"

Comment: You can see in the Postman console as described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60972054/how-to-view-the-redirection-chain-in-postman

Answer (score 105):

In the Settings `General` tab, turn off `Automatically follow redirects`.

> Automatically follow redirects: Prevent requests that return a
> 300-series response from being automatically redirected.

from https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/launching_postman/settings

Comment: Thanks, this is what I just needed as I can't see the authorization code being generated by Apigee as it automatically redirects to the site already with the code appended on the callback URL. But I can't see the callback url in postman. Doing this allowed me to see the callback url and the appdended authorization code in postmans header tab after sending the request. :)

Comment: It doesn't follow redirects alright, but then I have to manually follow the redirects myself by updating the target endpoint. I wish it would follow redirects automatically *_and_** also show all the redirects follow in the response, similar to how Chrome does in Developer Tools Network tab.

Comment: @JoseQuijada, you can check the outgoing requests in the `console` tab in postman's footer.

Answer (score 4):

You can see how Postman follows the redirects in the console in the footer as shown in the picture:

[image: Postman requests console - following redirects]