# How to create a 302 GET request with postman?

Tags: request, postman

In postman I want to create a GET request that returns a 302 status code (along with a `Location` response header). I have been trying to replicate the original request from the browser inspector, but I always get a 200 response (and no `Location` response header).

How can I get the desired response with the `Location` response header?

Answer (score 3):

Please try to turn off automatical redirects (File->Settings: General Tab):
[image]

Comment: Yes that kind of worked. I also get a `Location` parameter - but a very different one: All the params are missing completely!

Comment: What did you get, and what did you expect?

Comment: In the browser inspect its an URL with a lot of parameters, including the login token. In Postman its just the URL without any parameters. But I need that login token!

Comment: @Alex Do you mean in your browser, the `302` HTTP response has `Location` header, AND it also has login token etc.? That is a really weird situation.

Comment: The issue has been solved locally. Its related to OIDC login for wich a library can be used to handle all the requests in order to get a login session.

Comment: @Alex I'm having this same issue. I turned off redirects in Postman but I still can't seem to connect.

Answer (score 2):

What is probably happening is that Postman receives a 302 status code, but is configured to redirect in this case, so it automatically redirects after which Postman receives a 200 status code, which is what you end up seeing.

Apparently turning off "automatically follow redirects" should offer you a solution.
https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/launching_postman/settings/
[View postman request when redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49920152/view-postman-request-when-redirects)