# How to view the redirection chain in Postman?

Tags: php, http, postman, http-redirect

Sometimes I need to test websites that redirect single request multiple times. As a simple example, I created a sample script in PHP:

```
<?php

$n = (int) $_GET['n'] ?? 0;

if ($n < 9) header('Location: ?n=' . ($n + 1));
else echo $n;
```

I found out that Postman (by default?) allows up to <s>9</s> (see the EDIT below) 10 redirects and crashes on <s>10th</s> 11th. When I test that script in Postman, it shows the response of `9`, which is expected. What it's missing is the entire redirection chain, which I sometimes need to examine.

I know there's the *Automatically follow redirects* option, but it just doesn't follow redirections at all.

Is it possible to see all URLs that the request goes through? In my case that would be:

```
http://foo.test/
http://foo.test/?n=1
http://foo.test/?n=2
...
http://foo.test/?n=8
http://foo.test/?n=9
```

EDIT

It turned out one one my redirects was from `/directory` to `/directory/`, so the actual numbers of possible redirections are +1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can use the postman console to view all the urls.

See the red box on the left lower corner. Click on it to access the console.

Hope it helps :)

[image]

Comment: Thank you, brother. I figured out Postman allows actually 10, not 9 redirections. One extra redirection was from `/directory` to `/directory/`, as I put that script in a directory.