# Is there a way to get the URL after a redirect in postman?

Tags: url, redirect, postman

I'm working with an API, which after filling out the log in form on their website, redirects back to our website, with a unique code at the end of the URL.

Example URL after redirect:
https://www.mywebsite.com/?code=12431453154545

I have been unable to find a way of viewing this URL in Postman.

Ideally I need to be able to work with that URL to extract the code and store it as a variable.

Any help will be muchly appreciated. I've been trying this all day :( .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to retrieve the redirected url from a Postman response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56763018/is-there-a-way-to-retrieve-the-redirected-url-from-a-postman-response)

Comment: Thank you, but sadly not. I have tried that and it return an empty string

Answer (score 1):

When you [turn off following redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49920152/14967413) in Postman settings, you will be able to inspect `3xx` HTTP response which will contain `Location` header with the URL you want to read.

```js
const url = require("url");
var location = pm.response.headers.get("location");
if (typeof location !== typeof undefined) {
  var redirectUrl = url.parse(location, true);
  query = redirectUrl.query;
  if ("code" in query) {
    pm.globals.set("code", query.code);
    console.log(pm.globals.get("code"));
  }
}
```

Note that this solution will not work when multiple subsequent redirects happen as you will be inspecting only the first `3xx` response. You could solve this by following redirects manually and sending your own requests from Postman script as described in [Postman manual](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/postman-sandbox-api-reference/#sending-requests-from-scripts).

Comment: Thank you, the first method I had tried and doesn't work, returning the old url. And if I allow the redirect, I get nothing of use in the headers.But that link to the postman manual should be just what I'm looking for.